# How to check all desired files have been downloaded in shell script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, sendmail

I have downloaded the files from remote server by sftp.now i want to check that all of my files (nodeid given) have been donwloaded or not.if not downloaded then give the warning messages by sendmail.

**file_format**:

```
"$today_date"_MPS_Cust_dump_"$nodeid".list.Z
```

---

```
today_date=date +%Y%m%d
declare -a nodeid=("302" "303" "304" "305" "311" "312" "313" "314" "315" "316" "317" "318" 
  "410" "411" "412" "415" "416" "418" "431" "432" "433" "434" "435" "436" "407" "408" "409" 
  "401" "402" "420" "421" "422" "425" "426" "427" "403" "404" "405" "406"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
today_date="$(date +%Y%m%d)" # use $(...) to assign the output of a command to a variable
declare -a nodeid=(...)

for id in "${nodeid[@]}"; do
  [ -e "${today_date}_MPS_Cust_dump_${id}.list.Z" ] || echo "$id is not downloaded"
done | mail -E -s "Subject" user@example.com
```

---

- The for loop runs trough every item in the array `nodeid`.

  - `[ -e "..." ]` checks if the file exists with the given name in the current directory
  - `|| echo "..."` prints a message if the file doesn't exist
- `| mail ...` everything is piped to `mail`, `-s` defines the subject, `-E` will not send a mail when the body is empty (all files exist) and the last agument is the address.

Comment: Hi Chaos, the blank mail is still coming by this code even all files have been downloaded.

Comment: @user3548033 See my edit, add `-E` to the mail command

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you download these files to a temporary folder, then move them to the desired folder once download is complete.
So that you know that all the files in the desired folder are completely downloaded.